# Retrofit - Pass parameter in GET request with "/" form

Tags: android, parameters, get, retrofit

This is the API I want to get: http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=20/**genre=29**/explicit=true/json

How can I replace "29" by another number programmatically?

I have read many docs, but all of them have the same form with "?". Ex: https://api.example.com/tasks**?id=123**. I cannot apply their solution to my problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: genre=29 will be always 29 or it may also be some another number?

Comment: if i replace 29 by 22, 20, 25, etc,... the API will return the different result

Comment: You should replace nothing. Instead you should build up your url and add the parameters with their valus directly. Like it would be done if there was a ?

Comment: "29" can be replaced by other numbers returned from a different API. If I build up my url and add the parameters with their values directly, my code will so long :'(

Comment: try Query or Path annotations

Comment: I would fire you if you continued replacing 29's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

`@GET("users/{user}/repos")`

`Call<Response> listRepos(@Path("user") String user)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
int your_number = 20;
String url = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=20/genre=29/explicit=true/json;"
url = url.replace("genre=29", "genre"+your_number);
```

and now use url for requesting.

Comment: It does not work :( the method @GET(url) requires a final String url, I cannot assign a value to it :(

Comment: Yes. Whenever you are passing url pass it by running above code

Comment: In that case check if [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2) helps

Comment: Tks for your help! It works with changing BaseURL :D